# Dataframe calculation, anchor cell value to formula

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, character, calculation

I would like to do some calculations with the following dataframe. There are some values in specific cells of a column, and I would like to have them replicated based on a second column value, and store these in a new, third column:

```
x <- c ("1", "2","3", "4")
z <- (rep(x,5))
batch <- sort(z)
NDF <- rnorm(20, 10, 1); NDF <- signif (NDF, digits =3)
Fibre_analysis <- data.frame(batch, NDF)
Fibre_analysis$NDF[[1]] <- 10
Fibre_analysis$NDF[[6]] <- 100
Fibre_analysis$NDF[[11]] <- 1000
Fibre_analysis$NDF[[16]] <- 10000
```

This is the table that I would like:

```
   batch      NDF NEW_column
1      1    10.00         10
2      1    10.80         10
3      1     9.44         10
4      1    10.30         10
5      1    11.60         10
6      2   100.00        100
7      2     8.26        100
8      2     9.15        100
9      2     9.40        100
10     2     8.53        100
11     3  1000.00       1000
12     3     9.41       1000
13     3     9.20       1000
14     3    10.30       1000
15     3     9.32       1000
16     4 10000.00      10000
17     4    11.20      10000
18     4     7.33      10000
19     4     9.34      10000
20     4    11.00      10000
```

I would like this to create a new column in the dataframe, with absolute cell values from `$NDF`that have to change for each value of `$batch`.

Because I need to use this process more than once I created the following function:

```
batch_Function <- function (x,y){
        ifelse (x =="1", y[[1]],
                ifelse (x =="2", y[[6]],
                        ifelse (x =="3", y[[11]],
                                y[[16]] )))
        print (y)
}
```

when I call the function:

```
Fibre_analysis$NEW_column <- batch_Function ( Fibre_analysis$batch , Fibre_analysis$NDF )
```

I expect `$NEW_column` to look like this:

```
x <- c(10,100,1000,10000)
NEW_column <- rep(x, each=5)
```

whereas instead it is the exact same copy of the `$NDF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only necessary change is to drop `print(y)` as it is not allowing to return the actual result:

```
batch_Function <- function (x, y) {
  ifelse (x =="1", y[[1]],
          ifelse (x =="2", y[[6]],
                  ifelse (x =="3", y[[11]],
                          y[[16]] )))
}

batch_Function (Fibre_analysis$batch , Fibre_analysis$NDF )
#  [1]    10    10    10    10    10   100   100   100   100   100  1000  1000  1000  1000
# [15]  1000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000
```

In case you still want `print(y)`, you may put it at the beginning of `batch_Function`.

Comment: or assign result of first operation to a variable such as `output`, and end function with either `output` or `return(output)`